# Automatic cast of primary keys from identity (int) to String

Tags: java, sql-server, database, hibernate, identity

In our java Spring (Hibernate backed) application we are evaluating a massive transition from custom GUID generation for all the PKs to IDENTITY generation, since in our tests it performs better and is less disk space hungry.

At the moment we implement `varchar(36)` guids at database level (SQL Server 2012) and after having massively migrated all PKs into `IDENTITY INT` we are facing several problems in our application, all related to cast errors (obviously).

I'm wondering if there's a way, at database level, or ORM level, to convert all the retrieved PK columns from int to String, in order to avoid the massive refactoring in all our application (thousands of queries).

We use HBM mappings and this is our current setup in the mapping file for the ID:

```
<id name="id" column="id" >
   <generator class="identity"></generator>
  </id>
```

Our stack:

- Sql Server 2012
- Hibernate 4.3.5
- Spring 4.1.6

Edit: Adding table creation example script:

With **varchar(36) GUIDS**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test_table](
    [id] [varchar](36) NOT NULL     
 CONSTRAINT [PK_test_table] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

With **IDENTITY**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test_table](
    ..other columns...
    [id] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_test_table_id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: There is no SQL Server 2010. There was 2008, and 2008R2 and then it was 2012. What version are you actually using? You can find out my running `PRINT @@VERSION;` in SSMS, sqlcmd, etc.

Comment: A UUID is not an integer, and cannot be represented as such AFAIK.  Why are you switching from int to UUID?  Note that the most efficient way to store a UUID is as a 16 byte array.

Comment: Sorry @Larnu, it's the 2012 version

Comment: There is a specific data type in SQL Server for GUIDs as well, it's `uniqueidentifier`. a `varchar(36)` is a big data type for a PK, and if you're only going to be storing GUIDs, then why waste those 28 bytes? (`uniqueidentifier` is 16 bytes, where as a `varchar(n)` is `n+2` bytes in size; thus `36 + 2 = 38`).

Comment: We never used uniqueidentifier, although we researched a bit about it in the past. And yes, you're totally right about the waste of space, and that's a reason and DBA is trying this new approach with int identities.

I'm adding at the post the creation script of a table of example before and after the migration for clarity.